# RecyclerView blinks when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am facing the issue that my adapter blinks when `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,recyclerView.getChildCount())` is called. I have tried so many solutions like `setHasStableIds(true)` and overiding the `getItemId()` to return id but it doesn't help me.

```
if (page == 1) {
    homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), homeBeanList, Home.
    this, Home.
    this, Home.
    this, profile_pic, Home.
    this, Home.
    this, page);
    loaderDiloag.dismissDiloag();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
} else {
    if (homeAdapter != null) {
        try {
            loaderDiloag.dismissDiloag();
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            homeAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, recyclerView.getChildCount());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", e.toString() + "");
        }
    } else {
        try {
            homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), homeBeanList, Home.
            this, Home.
            this, Home.
            this, profile_pic, Home.
            this, Home.
            this, page);
            loaderDiloag.dismissDiloag();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", e.toString() + "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm facing this problem, also tried everything but without luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void removeBlinkAnimationWhenNewItemAdded(){
        ((SimpleItemAnimator)recyclerView).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false)
}
```